# How to save a drilled down version of a sunburst chart in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

I have a sunburst chart in plotly express. And I need the SVG of the chart. However, I can only write_image for the original chart, not any levels of drill down. Is there any way I could also export the drilled down sunburst chart?

Comment: So, you want to save all lower levels of sunburst chart?

Comment: @Phoenix Yes! Do you have any solutions?

Comment: But I think you will have different images for each level, is that ok for you?

Comment: @Phoenix Yes, if the levels are different, the images will be different.